# Using a few classes that use database connection

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class

Let's say I'm working on a forum, which of course has 
users, and options to add comments, open subjects etc.

Now for this thing I need to have some functions,
such as: logging in/out; adding/editting/deleting comments; private messages..Ok you got the point.

So if I do that with oop, for all these options using only one huge class would be very clumsy and I suppose less efficient,
so it's better to make a class for each one of the above. But the problem is that if I do so, I need to make a connection to database in each one of the classes,
and that would be a waste of resources to use more than one connetion to the same database at the same time. So, what's the best solution for this issue? :-)

Comment: Why do you suppose each class would need its own, separate connection script for the DB, rather than sharing a global (or at least globally accessible one)? In any case, in your case, why not have a general `Forum` class and have various other classes inherit from and extend it, for the various uses you describe.

Comment: If I share one connection resource (by parameter or by global variable), would it be efficient? And You're right about making one class that the others will inherit from. I hope that will achieve my goals. :-)

Comment: Never mind, I tried it and I figured it will not work out for me. I need other solution..\: BTW, does anyone know if using database singleton would be good in my situation?

Comment: Certainly more efficient than redeclaring and reconnecting for each code block. See answer.

Comment: An alternative to using a singleton would be to use Dependency Injection (see http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DependencyInjection), either by using a few conventions of your own (for example, by having each class take a database connection object as one of the arguments to its constructor), or using a dedicated dependency injection container like Pimple (http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/). Using DI can make your application easier to unit test

Answer (score 0):

In OOP you just create your objects. They do what they should do.

And when I write, you just create the objects, I mean that literally. There is no database so far, you don't care how these objects are stored yet.

Write your unit tests, get the objects to work what they should do.

Then start to bring those objects together. They still don't need to be stored. Just bring them together, like:

```
$user = $session->getUser();
$user->login(username, password);
```

And so on. Your application should just not need to care about the database.

Then when you finalize your application, next to where you instantiate the objects in each action, you also instantiate a `DataMapper` that is able to fetch object from the data-store.

```
User <--> UserMapper <--> Datastore
```

As you can see, the `User` object knows nothing about the `Datastore` , not even about the `UserMapper`. The `UserMapper` knows what a `User` is, but as written above, this comes later, so first get your important objects running, write the unit tests for them and then the integration tests and then when you've done that, start thinking about the database - whatever it will be then that time.

Answer (score -1):

OOP is all about the logical segregation of code into dedicated blocks, but with a basis for sharing, inheritance and interoperability where required. With this in mind, declare the connection as a static property of the class (since there is presumably no need for it to be recreated for each instance).

This would work (and be pretty efficient) whether your main code blocks are class extensions, or methods of, your base Forum class.

```
class Forum {
    public static $db = "I'm the database!";
    public function post() {
        echo self::$db;
    }
}
class Post extends Forum {
    public function getDB() {
        echo parent::$db;
    }
}

//post as its own sub-class
$post = new Post();
$post->getDB(); //I'm the database!

//post as method of class
$forum = new Forum();
$forum->post(); //I'm the database!
```

**[EDIT]** - it seems PHP cannot parse non-trivial values for static properties, i.e. they cannot be expressions or calls to functions.

One way round this is as follows:

```
class Forum {
    static $db;
    public function post() {
        self::$db; //do something with DB connection here
    }
}
Forum::$db = new mysqli(); //<-- the key - screw you, static property limitations
class Post extends Forum {
    public function getDB() {
        parent::$db; //do something with DB connection here
    }
}
```

...i.e. we declare the static property (our DB handler) after the class declaration. Someone else might know a more graceful way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have the same resource through all of the classes, not the data for the connection..So, how can I do that? I tried to have a static variable which has the connetion, but it gave me an error for an unexpected "new". (for the - new mysqli(...))

Comment: Interesting. Having looked into this, it turns out [PHP cannot parse non-trivial values assigned to static properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). Answer edited to include a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code. Save it by the name of Databasehandler.php. and include it in your index.php and use its functions whenever needed throughout your whole project. It uses PDO to make secure queries to your database. Minor modifications maybe necessary.

```
    <?php

Class DatabaseHandler
{
    private static $_mhandler;

    private function __construct() { }

    private static function GetHandler()
    {
        if(!isset($_mhandler))
        {
            try
            {
                self::$_mhandler = new PDO (PDO_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => DB_PERSISTENCY));
                self::$_mhandler -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                self::Close();
                trigger_error($e -> getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
            }

            return self::$_mhandler; // Returning DATABASE Handler Object.
        }
    }

    public static function Close()
    {
        $_mhandler = NULL;
    }

    public static function Execute($sqlquery, $params = NULL)
    {
        try
        {
            $dbh = self::GetHandler(); //DataBaseHandler
            $sth = $dbh -> prepare($sqlquery); //StatementHandler
            $sth -> execute($params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            self::Close();
            trigger_error($e -> getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }

    }

    public static function GetAll($sqlquery, $params = NULL, $fetchstyle = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    {
        $result = NULL;

        try
        {
            $dbh = self::GetHandler();
            $sth = $dbh -> prepare($sqlquery);
            $sth -> execute($params);
            $result = $sth -> fetchAll($fetchstyle);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            self::Close();
            trigger_error($e -> getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        return $result;
    }


    public static function GetRow($sqlquery, $params = NULL, $fetchstyle = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
    {
        $result = NULL;

        try
        {
            $dbh = self::GetHandler();
            $sth = $dbh -> prepare($sqlquery);
            $sth -> execute($params);
            $result = $sth -> fetch($fetchstyle);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            self::Close();
            trigger_error($e -> getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        return $result;
    }


    public static function GetOne($sqlquery, $params = NULL)
    {
        $result = NULL;

        try
        {
            $dbh = self::GetHandler();
            $sth = $dbh -> prepare($sqlquery);
            $sth -> execute($params);
            $result = $sth -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            $result = $result[0];
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            self::Close();
            trigger_error($e -> getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use this class with another class? Because as I said, I need to have more than one class with db connection, so I would really appreciate a code that fully describes this. Thx :)

Comment: Yes... just create an instance of it.